# Mocked object to return actual data

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, servlets, mockito

```
//MyServlet.java
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, Exception {

         int sum = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("a")) + Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("b"));

         request.setAttribute("sum",sum);
         RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/ShowSum.jsp");
         dispatcher.forward(request,response);
} 
}




  //TestServelt.java

 public class TestServelt {
  @Test
public void testSum() throws Exception {
    HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);       
    HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = mock(RequestDispatcher.class);
   when(request.getParameter(a)).thenReturn(10);
    when(request.getParameter(b).thenReturn(20);
    when(request.getRequestDispatcher(anyString())).thenReturn(dispatcher);
    MyServlet  testServlet =  new MyServlet ();
    testServlet.doPost(request, response); 

    int sum = (int)request.getAttribute("sum"); // here it's will return NULL.
   }
}
```

I am trying to write somewhat similar Test case for a servlet 
as u can see , that sum variable can't be mocked cuz that will defeat the purpose , i want it to return what got calculated after the servlet call. can anyone help or give a different approach.

Comment: "it's returning null on NavigationParams where as NavigationParams is getting set on servlet call" <-- maybe so, but you don't mock the appropriate method, so Mockito does the default here. What method is that? .setAttribute(), another one?

Comment: I don't get it. You're mocking the request, POSTing and then want to assert on attributes in the mocked request? What is your test case here?

Comment: i can't set anything , NavigationParams are getting set on servlet call , but my request object is mocked but i don't want to mock request.getAttribute("NavigationParams") , i want it to return what was actually calculated on servlet call.

Comment: @Ander , Servlet requires say example , attribute a , b and c , this request is getting dispached to other URL with change in request object those changes are not part of my input to servlet it's part of my output in this case.

Comment: say there is a servlet which takes a and b as params and puts in new parameter sum where sum = a + b , and this request object is dispached to JSP page where it shows , SUM = 30 , now i mocked the input a as 10 and b as 20 , but i can't mock it's answer as well , if i do what's the point of testing.

Comment: OK, so, it is you which sets this `NavigationParam` stuff, right? How? Using which code?

Comment: forget about navigationParams , lets just take sum = a + b , if i understand how i can do this then i can do that as well , 
give me 2 min , i am changing the complete Q and posting complete code.

Comment: Please check original post again.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use mock objects in this case; mock objects are just thin API layers, they have no functionality or intelligence.

Use a framework with simulates the Servlet API like [mockrunner](http://mockrunner.github.io/) or the [Spring Web testing framework](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/spring-mvc-integration-tests.html).